# Discord Command Prompt Error with Constants

Tags: javascript, discord

When I would enter

"node index.js"

Into Command Prompt & the folder with all of the Discord bot information, it'd give me this error:

```
const client = Discord.Client();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token const
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Anyway to fix?

Edit:

config.json

```
{ 
"BOT_TOKEN": "bot's token"
}
```

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('bot's token');
```

Comment: Hi crep, can you post the code you are working with so we can identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, you have probably put one of these somewhere in the code: (maybe by accident in another .js file?)

```
const client = Discord.client();
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token const, usually means the app waited for some kind of const, but did not receive it.
Also, try to move the 'Token' constant in your index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

It's suggesting somewhere in your code you have `const client = Discord.Client();`. Once found just remove it.

**Advice**

I'd suggest you refer to your `config.json` .

The following:

```
const settings = require('./config.json')
```

Then extract bot token by making a variable:

```
const token = settings.BOT_TOKEN;
```

Result:

```
client.login(token);
```

*Optimises your code ;)*